# Can i use the mql4 AlgLib library for solving Second Order Linear Homogeneous Differential Equations with Variable Coefficients

Tags: differential-equations, mql4, mql, alglib

I have this formula:

`$$\frac{d^2Q(t)}{dt^2} + \frac{\omega(t)}{2\pi} \frac{dQ(t)}{dt} + \omega^{2}(t)Q(t) = 0, $$`

where `$ \omega(t)= \frac{2\pi}{v(t)} \frac{dv}{dt}  $` and `$v>0$` is a known parameter which is given from a data feed.

I have already built some visualization by using Mathematica.

Now i need to proceed further with mt4 technical indicator charts so
can i use ODEsolver from AlgLib by  Runge-Kutta-Cash-Karp method with mql4 as the above equation has time dependent coefficients.